# IncompatibleRemoteServiceException when refreshing dev mode on firefox 16.0 (after GWT 2.5 upgrade)

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-rpc, dev-mode, gwt-2.5

We recently upgraded from GWT 2.4 to 2.5.  Everything seemed to be working until I started working in dev mode again.

When I initially load my application everything runs fine, however when I try to click my browser refresh button the entire application is unable to make RPC calls.  I get the following exception (or similar) when my application tries to make a GWT-RPC call after hitting the refresh button (regardless of whether changes were made or not)

NOTE:  This only appears to be a problem on Firefox (version 16). Not Chrome.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The response could not be deserialized
    at com.printlogix.rp.client.pages.sales.SalesPanel$22.onFailure(SalesPanel.java:260)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The response could not be deserialized
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:221)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find class com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_FieldSerializer
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:164)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find class com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_FieldSerializer
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:93)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:160)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MultiParentClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:368)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:388)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ReflectionHelper.loadClass(ReflectionHelper.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:160)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
ERROR: InvocationException occured
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 0 
    at com.printlogix.rp.client.util.ClientSessionAndCodebaseDetector.onFailure(ClientSessionAndCodebaseDetector.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 0 
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Update:  I am starting to think this could be a problem with the Intellij/GWT configuration.  Intellij is responsible for passing in the classpath to dev mode as needed.

Update:  I have confirmed that if I run dev mode from the command line reloading is not a problem.  It is only when I run through Intellij Idea 11 or 12's GWT run configuration.

Comment: Did you make sure that your server uses the `gwt-servlet.jar` from GWT 2.5?

Comment: Could it be related to your GWT browser plugin version? Maybe it is outdated.

Comment: No I reinstalled the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Just a silly question:
You think is a Intellij IDEA problem. So, did you already tried another ide? Just to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

yes its a IDE refresh problem. When ever u change the code IDE executes build on the project and pushes the required changes to the target folder. Unfortunately this is not the case everytime. Some times it fails to push the changes in to the target folder. One example is when u change the DTO/Model object structure.

Solution is simple, delete the target folder in your project and execute the build on the project.